# Special characters being removed automatically from request

Tags: java, jsp, request

I am setting notes(String) which contains a mix of special char's, number, alphabets, etc, in a hidden variable `notesValue`, and opening a new jsp(nextPage).

```
var Url='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/nextPage.jsp?notesValue='+document.forms[0].notesValue.value;

var Bars = 'directories=no, location=no,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no';
var Options='scrollbar=yes,width=350,height=200,resizable=no';
var Features=Bars+' '+Options;
alert("Url being sent ---> "+Url);
var Win=open(Url,'Doc5',Features);
```

At nextPage.jsp side, am doing:

```
String notes = request.getParameter("notesValue");
```

Here am getting only plain text and all the special characters are gone.

For eg: notesValue which I set was: "New Notes &';>/..."

What I received on `nextPage.jsp` is : New Notes\

What's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the `string result`

`encodeURIComponent(document.forms[0].notesValue.value);`

No need to add any `plugin`.Its built in `function`.

Comment: Using 'encodeURIComponent' did the trick. Thanks a lot. One doubt, I am just calling a jsp (with window.open) from javascript of other jsp. Where is Get and Post involved in this ? How can I convert this to POST ?

Comment: I misunderstood.You are not using any form right?? So encode data is enough.

Comment: Yes. If I am calling any servlet, I usually use method="post"

Comment: If you use html forms then GET and POST  comes in to picture.As of now they are not related to your line,As you are directlly triggering the url

Answer (score 1):

When you are sending data using this method :

```
nextPage.jsp?notesValue='+document.forms[0].notesValue.value;
```

You are using `GET` method for sending the data as you are appending the data with the URL. But there are many special characters invloved have special meaning in the URL (like `&`,`>`,`<`,`;`, etc.)

When these characters are not used in their special role inside a URL, they need to be encoded

so you need to encode them first if you need to send them as values o that they are not considered as special URL characters.

[Here's a list of URL character encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

You can use `POST` method instead to avoid this.

Also read this: 
[How to encode URL in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Comment: That was informative abu. +1 for that. How can I make it POST ? encodeURIComponent did the trick